# How can I upload an image in ASP.NET Core and save it to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new, I don't know how to upload and save an image to a SQL Server database using Entity Framework Core code-first approach in asp.net core mvc.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: my local apps is connected to SQL server on Azure. I don't know the version number  must be latest.

Comment: Ok, cool, then you can take advantage of blob storage in SQL Azure. Have a look at this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs

Answer (score 1):

1.Concert Image to Base64

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}

2. after concerting Base64String , you create Column with Name Image with type String then save Base64 String in Sql server Table
```

Comment: Base64 encoded string takes up more space in database compare to byte array. Would you care to explain why you suggest that option?

Comment: ok,i am working on Nop commerce Site in MVC, in this They  Saved all image in  database, that way i am Suggesting for this way , but there is also other way to store Image , we save image in Soultion folder and Image Path Save on Database Table

Comment: Can you please create a Model class , Controller and save that to the SQL server database using Entity Framework core? I am new so  I don't know  about previous  version of asp.net and entity framework.